# Is it illegal to supply a false address to a bank?

Tags: fraud, perjury

Can somebody get in trouble for supplying a false address to a bank when opening an account?

Comment: "*last i checked, lying was not a crime*" - https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/1344 If you get *anything* of value from your bank: a loan, interest on deposits, etc. based on your fraudulent pretences, you would be in violation of 18 USC 1344.

Comment: I edited away all the unnecessary details and stripped the question down to what I think was the basic question you were asking. Did I summarize correctly?

Comment: There could be laws that make it illegal to knowingly provide false information on those forms specifically. I wouldn't do it. I can't imagine it's a crime to be homeless, and I'm relatively certain there must be a way to do the things you're asking about without a residential address. Did you talk to them? What did they say to do?

Comment: i think lying to the government agency probably has different consequences than lying to a private company. most of the case law i can find is about passports, but i assume  licenses are similar. perhaps that is a separate question?

Comment: @Dawn i don't think that my residential address is "material" to opening the account.  specifically, i don't think the bank cares, it is just some homeland security regulations with which they must comply. besides, i am not receiving funds from the bank in question, i am giving them my funds.

Comment: @Patrick87 in both cases i was told that i must provide documentation of a residential address.  both clerks recommended i provide the address of a family member or a homeless shelter.  neither of which seems any more honest than the previous address i provided.

Comment: @james 1344 does not have a materiality component. When you deposit money, you get interest.

Comment: @jamesturner, lying to the government need not be directly between you and the government agency. See United States v. Yermian 468 U.S. 63, where he lied to defense contractor, who gave his false information to the government. Banks report things to the government, which would be the conduit for charges of violating 18 USC 1001.

Comment: @user6726 i think your application of this precedent is absurdly broad. if you assume all banking agreements fall "within the jurisdiction of any department or agency of the United States", then is there any matter that is not within the jurisdiction of a federal agency? it seems that this statute as interpreted could be used to convict anyone who ever lied about anything as mundane as their secret cookie recipe.

Comment: @jamesturner, you should read Yermian. If the bank supplies information to the government in satisfaction of a requirement to track bank customers, then it is in the technical sense a matter in the jurisdiction of the government. I personally disagree with the court's interpretation of the "knowingly" clause, but that is now the established law.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the label on [18 USC 1014](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/1014) might suggest that you only get in trouble for lying on a loan application, the language of the statute includes "Whoever knowingly makes any false statement …for the purpose of influencing in any way the action of…any institution the accounts of which are insured by the Federal Deposit Insurance Corporation…shall be fined not more than $1,000,000 or imprisoned not more than 30 years, or both". Which I think counts as trouble, if you're in the US. There are, additionally, options for charges of fraud, and probably lying to the government on the premise that account information is transmitted to the feds (likely mediated through the fact that the federal government insures tour accounts)

Comment: 1. i am not sure this counts as "for the purpose of influencing", since i don't think the agencies involved will behave differently based on the address i provide.  2.  shouldn't there be some materiality test during the adjudication of these charges?

Comment: As for 2, perhaps, but that is not what the law says. Write to your congressman, or favorite SCOTUS justice. You are free to argue that the bank would not have been influenced, but then you would have to explain why you didn't tell the truth. The prosecution will have a story about why you *were* trying to influence the bank, and the jury isn't going to believe an unsubstantiated denial.

Comment: i think the fact that i tried to tell the truth and they refused to believe me would be sufficient for any reasonable jury.